# Can't get correct Eloquent association on polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I have resources that have a privacy setting applied to them. Namely Community and Event. I created a morphOne relationship on all the resources that will require privacy like so

```
public function privacy(){
    return $this->morphOne('App\Privacy', 'privacy_resource');
}
```

I am able to query the privacy setting for collections like so

```
$profile->events()->with('privacy')->get();
```

But when I attempt this on an individual resource like so

```
$event->with('privacy')->get();
```

I instead get a collection of all items from that resource.

I realize that I might be misusing `get()` here and its actually getting all the events that have a privacy setting on them. Is there something other than `get` that I should be using here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you already retrieved the model, you can use `load` instead of `with`.

```
$event->load('privacy');
```

This is called [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading).

In the statement `$profile->events()->with('privacy')->get();` on the other hand, you did not yet retrieve the event models from the database. That is why you can use the `with` method here, which will add a join to the query.

Comment: User could also do `$event->privacy()->get();` to query the Privacy objects attached to that specific Event without affecting `$event`.